# Correlation Coefficient Var(X)

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables with distributions $N(2,3)$ and $N(3,2)$ respectively. Let

I'm having trouble understanding how to find $Var(X)$ and $Var(Y)$ for the correlation coefficient between $Z$ and $W$.

$Z = 2X + Y$

$W = X - 3Y$

I have 
$Cov(Z, W) = Cov(2X + Y , X - 3Y )$

$= Cov(2X, X) + Cov(2X, -3Y ) + Cov(Y , X) + Cov(Y ,  -3Y )$

$= 2Cov(X, X) - 6Cov(X, Y ) + Cov(Y , X) -  3Cov(Y , Y )$

$= 2Var(X) -  0 + 0  - 3Var(Y ) = 6 - 6 = 0.$

Why is $Var(x) = 3$ and $Var(Y) = 2?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given them in the statement of the question

Comment: sorry where? I don't understand

Comment: Do you understand Normal distribution? It is written N(x,y^2) where x is the mean and y^{2} is the variance. In the first line

Comment: appreciate that, are you ready for the 323 final?

Comment: Nice catch :)   Hope so

Comment: Do you get it now or are you still not sure ?